# How can I save the data from my Django crispy form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, crud, django-crispy-forms

This is how my form looks like: [image]

When I press submit and go to the page where the post should be rendered, then I cannot see the post I just have created.

This is the page where I have my form: 'anzeige_new.html'

```
  {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
  {% block content %}
        <div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Inserat erstellen</legend>
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
  {% endblock content %}
```

This is where it should be rendered: "angebote.html"

```
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
  <p>Inside for loop</p>
  <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ Post.objects.all }}</a>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
      </div>
      <h2><a class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # If you pass FormHelper constructor a form instance
        # It builds a default layout with all its fields
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

        # You can dynamically adjust your layout
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save', 'save'))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'category', 'weekday')
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='SOME STRING')


    weekday_choices = (
        ('Monday', 'Monday'),
        ('Tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
        ('Wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
        ('Thursday', 'Thursday'),
        ('Friday', 'Friday'),
        ('Saturday', 'Saturday'),
        ('Sunday', 'Sunday'),
    )

    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=weekday_choices, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'category', 'weekday']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'vereinsapp/angebote.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']  # ordering posts from latest to oldest


class CreateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'vereinsapp/anzeige_new.html'
    print("Inside Create View")
    def post(self, request):
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            post = form.save()
            post.save()
            form = PostForm()
            post = form.save()
            return redirect('post:posts')

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('vereinsapp/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('angebote/', views.angebote),
    path('angebotsprofil/', views.angebotsprofil),
    path('vereinsmarketing/', views.vereinsmarketing),
    path('anzeige_new/', views.anzeige_new),
    path('nutzerprofil/', views.nutzerprofil),

    path('posts/', PostListView.as_view(), name='posts'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
]
```

Why is it still not saving?

UPDATE/EDIT:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'vereinsapp/angebote.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']  # ordering posts from latest to oldest
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

angebote.html

```
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
  <p>Inside for loop</p>
  <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post }}</a>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.weekday }}</small>
      </div>
      <h2><a class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ post.category }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you are not passing the queryset of posts to be displayed on the "angebote.html" page. In the PostListView, you are supposed to define the queryset that should be displayed. For example, you can set it as queryset = Post.objects.all() in the PostListView.

Then in the template "angebote.html" you can iterate over the queryset to display the post data.

Also, in your template <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ Post.objects.all }}</a> should be <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ posts }}</a>. Same thing goes for the line <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url">

Comment: you mean like that?>see my edits above

Comment: No, that is not what I meant.
You should set the queryset variable on the PostListView class like this: queryset = Post.objects.all()
And in your template, you can iterate over the queryset by using the context_object_name you defined in the class, which is posts in your case: {% for post in posts %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
You don't need to call queryset variable in the template.

Comment: Ok so : I already have added "queryset = Post.objects.all()" to "PostListView". Now I changed {% for post in queryset %}  to {% for post in posts %}. But its still not working....